# What does the "Core Animation Layer" setting do in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, core-animation, layer

I am writing a Xamarin Mac application that has several view's in one window. I am having a hard time implementing a visual element tree since there is no documentation from Xamarin on this, but even more confusing is Views nesting in Xcode Interface Builder. Particularly, I see that the setting called `Core Animation Layer` affects which controls appear or not on the window. I can't find any documentation on this particular setting so I'd appreciate a quick explanation on what is done with these checkmarks, or, please point me to a tutorial or an article I can read about it. Thanks you!
[image]

Comment: OS X or iOS application?

Comment: The [Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) would be a good place to start.